# Using ecto changeset to enforce authorization on entities

Tags: authorization, elixir, ecto

This may be beyond the scope of changesets but I thought I'd check if there's an elegant way of doing this. In my Phoenix application I have **users**, **teams** and **matches**.

There is a relation between them as follows:

```
user --has_many--> team --has_many--> match
```

Users can create matches with one of the parameters being `team_id`. I want to ensure that when a user creates a match the `team_id` is the ID of a team that is owned by the user.

The method for doing this currently looks like this:

```
  def create_match(_root, params, %{context: %{current_user: user}}) do
    case Repo.get_by(Team, %{id: params.team_id, user_id: user.id}) do
      nil ->
        {:error, "Team does not exist for user"}

      team ->
        Match.changeset(%Match{team_id: team.id}, params)
        |> Repo.insert()
    end
  end
```

So I'm checking that a team with the provided `team_id` exists for the user making the request before making a changeset for the match.

Is there any way this can be expressed as a constraint/validation in the changeset itself? It would be nice to express this as just another validation error that my frontend can handle.

Comment: I believe you can have your own changeset validation. Just use `add_error/4` https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#add_error/4

Comment: Nice, yeah that is an improvement. I was wondering if I could define a custom validation/constraint on the changeset itself though.

Comment: _“I could define a custom validation/constraint on the changeset”_ what does it suppose to mean? Add `validate_my_constraint/2` returning `Ecto.Changeset` to your schema and call it as all other validations from your `changeset/2` callback.

Comment: You *could* move this logic to the changeset functions, but you probably shouldn't. If you do move this logic into your changeset functions, you will be blurring the line between user authorization and data validation. It will create a coupling that you will most likely regret later. The way you have it in your example is the recommended way to do authorization. There are also many authorization libraries that you could incorporate to streamline your implementations.

Comment: OK thanks. I actually ended up using the changeset to express the error whilst keeping the logic itself in the resolver (but it could be a controller method). Good to get some sanity